# Why list cross files have different id?

Tags: python

I have two scripts, `test1.py` and `test2.py`, with the following contents:

```py
# test1.py

box = []

def run():
    box.append(20)
    box.append(30)
    print(box)
    print(f'test1 {id(box)}')

    from test2 import b
    print(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

```py
# test2.py

from test1 import box

print(f'test2 {id(box)}')
box.append(40)
b = box
```

And this is the result I get when I run `test1.py`:

```py
[20, 30]
test1 4320983560
test2 4320994504
[40]
```

In my opinion `box` is a mutable object, so the final result should be `[20, 30, 40]`, but in fact, `box` in `test1.py` and `test2.py` has a different id and it looks not the same one. This confuses me, can anybody tell me why?

Comment: please don't send code as photo, send as code block

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Comment: how is that the result when you run the test2.py?? i think you meant by running test1.py

Comment: btw. good question. i've imported a list from a module and it had the same address in both scripts. your case is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In `test2.py` when you imported `test1` it went to the file, and imported `a` like it say on the first line:

```py
a = []
```

It doesn’t matter that you first ran
`test1.py` script and imported `test2` from it. Once

`from test1 import a`

is imported, you only import an empty list. It doesn’t use the `run` function as well, this is happen only if `test1` isn’t imported.